# How to do filter for products (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I do the online shop. I have 3 pages where filters for products are similar - Catalog page, parent category page and children category page

```
site/catalog/  // catalogController@index
site/catalog/parentCategory/childrenCategory //childrenCategoryController@index
site/catalog/parentCategory //parentCategoryController@index
```

The filter is made via get requests, like that: `site/catalog?price_from=1&price_to=9999&color=red`. How to make this filter into a separate function? Will it be good to make this in a product model? And how to use it? I think it should be a function that accepts 2 params (request params and current query model) and returns `$this`.

Code in controllers:

```
$products = Product::filter($products, $request)->paginate(20);
```

Model:

```
public function filter($model, Request $request) {
        if ($request->has('price_from')) {
            $model->where('price', '>', $request->get('price_from'));
        }
        if ($request->has('color')) {
            $model->where('color', '>', $request->get('color'));
        }

        return $model;
    }
```

But how to do it right? How to pass current `$products` in controller code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes). Something like:

```
public function scopeFilter($q)
{
    if (request('price_from')) {
        $q->where('price', '>', request('price_from'));
    }
    if (request('color')) {
        $q->where('color', '>', request('color'));
    }

    return $q;
}
```

Then use it:

```
Product::filter()->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Thank you! Should I pass the request parameter in same function from controller? Or how should I get the $request variable?

Comment: @Alexxosipov you can just use `request()` helper as I've shown.

Comment: i have implemented that feature in my avored laravel ecommerce take a look here. https://github.com/avored/laravel-ecommerce

Answer (score -3):

Had to do something like this recently, here is my whole `ProductsController.php` file:
`

```
         <?php
         namespace App\Http\Controllers;
         use Illuminate\Http\Request;
         use App\Product;

        class ProductsController extends Controller
        {
            public function index(Request $request)
            {
                $products = Product::get();

                if ($request->type) {
                    $products = $products->whereIn('type', $request->type);
                }
        
                if ($request->gender) {
                  $products = $products->whereIn('gender', $request->gender);
                }

               return $products;
```

`

You can continue adding on and filter as much as needed, worked like a charm for me, note that I used `whereIn()` as my requested data was coming in as an array, hope this helps.

Comment: You are grabbing all products. If you have many products you will max memory.

Comment: The point of the answer was about  explaining the usage of `whereIn` method, but if that bothers you so much, there, I fixed it :)